# NPM globally installed package cannot be found

Tags: npm

I tried to install the "progress" package globally but got an error.
[image]

I made sure that npm's root path is located in my $PATH.
[image]

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

If you need `require("project")` then you need to install the project **locally**.

Global installation only works when you are installing a Command Line Interface tool, such as "jshint"

In my situation, because I need to use the module "progress" in my code. I must npm install locally.

---

**Update**

If saving space is what you are after. Like installing a single package globally to be reused by many projects. You can use `--link` flag that will create a symbolic link to the global installation. So instead of `npm install express` you can do `npm install express --link`.